# ARSCNView before iOS 11.0

Tags: storyboard, swift4, xcode9, arkit, arscnview

I'm trying to add ARKit to one of my existing apps, and I'm making that transition to the view when you click a button. I made the button only available if you have iOS 11 so you'll only be able to go to that view with iOS 11, but how do I get rid of this error for the Storyboard?

Class Unavailable ARSCNView before iOS 11.0

Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

I guess this answers your question

> Not creating ARSCNView in a storyboard, but initializing one and
>   adding it to your view controller's root view in code.

[Replacement for ARKit in iOS10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45332261/replacement-for-arkit-in-ios10)

Or you can go to your XIB view and make it Builds for iOS 11 or Later.
[image: Builds for iOS 11 or Later]